# Remove/find invalid iptables entries?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I've tried to install a firewall such as ufw on my Xen Debian VPS, however it just would not start up no matter what I had done, so I had looked for a more suited firewall, arno-iptables-firewall.

Unfortunately, when I start it up it lists about fifty iptables warnings:

```
/sbin/iptables: (1) iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
/sbin/iptables: (1) iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
/sbin/iptables: (1) iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
/sbin/iptables: (1) iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
/sbin/iptables: (1) iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
(and thirty or so more)
```

I am not entirely sure where they come from, however the firewall functions flawlessly for what I need to use it for.

My question is: how do I remove the offending entries so it does not bother me when I restart them? is there a way to do this without rebuilding the list?

And also: If I were to flush the list, would things be fine networking wise once I install the firewall again, or will I remove essential entries left by the system beforehand? I am not entirely sure where the entries came in to my system.

Comment: What do you get when running `iptables -L -v -n`?

Comment: @quanta, here you go: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xUfp9EAE

Answer (score 0):

1. Do an `iptables -nL --line` to see the rules. Check the line numbers.
2. Delete the ones causing the issue using `iptables [-t table] -D <chain> <line no>`

Comment: My issue is that I could not find the exact entries my firewall is complaining about, it's like saying "30 of your 100 entries are incorrect" without a clue what.